# How to select an image in a screen and display it on another using kivy?

Tags: image, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a simple, two-screen interface with Kivy for an image classification task. In the first screen, I am selecting an image using the file chooser and displaying it. In the second screen, I want to show the same image and the result of the classification task. The transition between screens is done via a button on the first screen.

My question is: When I press the button, how can I trigger an update of the image source property on the second screen, such that the chosen image will be displayed on the second screen?
The classification part is just to understand the background of my question, I did not include it in the code.

Here is the `main.py` file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    image_source = StringProperty()
    def selected(self,filename):
        try:    
            self.image_source = filename[0]
        except:
            pass
    
# Screen where the image is selected
class ImageSelector(Screen):
    pass

# Display image & classification results
class ClassificationResultWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):        
        self.image_selector = ImageSelector()
        self.scan_result_window = ClassificationResultWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And here is the `main.kv` file

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
WindowManager:
    ImageSelector:
    ClassificationResultWindow:

<ImageSelector>:
    name: "image_selector"
    id: image_selector
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: image_box
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: 
                root.manager.selected(filechooser.selection)
                print(root.manager.image_source)             
            size_hint: 1, 10           
        Image:
            id: image
            source: root.manager.image_source
            size_hint: 1, 4 
        Button:
            id: diagnose
            text: "Classify"
            on_release: 
                print(root.manager.image_source) 
                app.root.current = "classification_result"

<ClassificationResultWindow>:
    name: "classification_result"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: box
        Image:
            id: scan
            source: root.manager.image_source
            size_hint: 1, 10        
        Label:
            text: "Here comes the classification result"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 1, 2
            id: label
```

I tried without success binding the property in different ways, but since I'm new to kivy I didn't know if it makes sense so I didn't include them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I handle passing information from one screen onto the other is by having the `ScreenManager` hold properties, and have the `Screen` access them.

Your `main.py` file should now be:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    image_source = StringProperty()
    def selected(self,filename):
        try:    
            self.image_source = filename[0]
        except:
            pass
    
# Screen where the image is selected
class ImageSelector(Screen):
    pass

# Display image & classification results
class ClassificationResultWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    pass     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
WindowManager:
    ImageSelector:
    ClassificationResultWindow:

<ImageSelector>:
    name: "image_selector"
    id: image_selector
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: image_box
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: 
                root.manager.selected(filechooser.selection)          
            size_hint: 1, 10           
        Image:
            id: image
            screen: image_selector 
            source: self.screen.manager.image_source
            size_hint: 1, 4 
        Button:
            id: diagnose
            text: "Classify"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "classification_result"

<ClassificationResultWindow>:
    name: "classification_result"
    id: classification_results
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: box
        Image:
            id: scan
            screen: classification_results
            source: self.screen.manager.image_source
            size_hint: 1, 10        
        Label:
            text: "Here comes the classification result"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 1, 2
            id: label
```

What is going on? So first a `StringProperty` is created in the `ScreenManager`. Bindings to these properties are automatically created and thus things referencing this property will update as it is changed.

Then the `Image` class in each `Screen` references this `StringProperty` through `root.manager.image_source`.

- `root` is the root widget,
- `manager` is a property that each screen has which points it towards its parent `ScreenManager`
- `image_source` is the property we created earlier.

Hope this helps. I have not tested the above, so there may be an error or two, but I think the general concept of having the `ScreenManager` hold objects that `Screen`'s need to pass on to one another is how I solve this issue.

Comment: I should add that changes will happen instantly (because of the automatic binding). You can always delay this by creating a function that access the property, i.e. in your `selected()` function write `self.ids.image.source = self.manager.image_source`. That way you can control when one screen access the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made some small changes but I still can't make it work. This line `source: root.manager.image_source` throws the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_source'`.  When pressing the button, I included `print(root.manager.image_source)` and this shows the correct path. I don't understand why this cannot be accessed in the image source. I updated my initial code based on your suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm, try variations of this. First try `root.parent.manager.image_source`, then try `self.parent.parent.manager.image_source`. If none of them work give your image a `manager` attribute. To do this first give each `Screen` an id (in the KV file), something like `id: _screen` then for the `Image` class give them a screen attribute `screen: _screen`. Hopefully then you should be able to refer to the image source by passing `source: self.screen.manager.image_source`

Comment: Awesome. The last suggestion worked, I gave each screen an id and then used this as the `screen` attribute in the `Image` class and referred the source as `source: self.screen.manager.image_source`. I changed your answer to incorporate the comments. Do you know why it worked?

Comment: Yes, so your newly created id is a `ObjectProperty` which points to the `Screen`, and works in the same way that `parent` or `root` works. In fact this is a great way of having widgets “talk” to one another. Suppose you want to update a `Label` based on a `TextInput`. Create an id for the label, then use the above technique to store a reference to this label in the TextInput. Finally you can create a binding by declaring `self.label.text = self.text`.

Comment: I should specify that this only works this easily in the KV file, as Kivy will automatically create bindings for each of these properties. It becomes quite a bit more difficult when these relationships between widgets are established in the Python file, as you'll have to create the bindings yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Now it's much clearer.